# Change one field value by changing another field value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Two input fields `total_bill` & `delivery_charge_bill`.

`total_bill` field already have a value, now I want that when I input some value into `delivery_charge` field that will change the `total_bill` field's value.

Suppose `total_bill` field's value is `200`.

Now I input `20` into `delivery_charge` field and that will effect the `total_bill` field and the value will be `220`.

For any type of changes of `delivery_charge` field it will change the value of `total_bill` field.

But for myself it will not change perfectly.

Suppose `total_bill` is `200`

when input `delivery_charge` = `2`

`total_bill` = `202`

when input `delivery_charge` = `20`

`total_bill` = `2020`

Here is my code detail

**html**

```
<h4>Grand Total : <input type="number" id="total_bill" readonly class="form-control total_amount" value="0.00"></h4>

<input type="text" name="delivery_charge" id="delivery_charge" class="form-control">
```

**js**

```
$('#delivery_charge').keyup(function(event) {
            var total_amount = $('.total_amount').val();
            var delivery_charge = $(this).val();
            var grand_total_amount = total_amount + delivery_charge;
            $('.total_amount').val(grand_total_amount);
});
```

Anybody help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 5 hours ago you ask same question !

Comment: @haldo....not yet.....

Comment: *...not yet...* - then edit the original question. why have you posted the exact same question twice?

Comment: The answer provided on your other question does exactly what you've asked for.   If you're unable to get it to work, you should add a comment *to that answer* detailing what you've done, maybe with a link to a fiddle so someone can point out where you're going wrong.

Comment: Any answer provided to *this* question, will be *exactly the same as the answer you already have* - ie, store `total_amount` *first* and convert the input to an integer.  `200 + "2" = "2002"` means you're adding as strings, not converting to a number *first*, but `200 + ("2" * 1) = 202`.  This is what the existing answer is telling you.

Comment: You *can* ask a **new** question, but you should reference the old question and include what you've done since asking that question and what's still not working.

Comment: @haldo.... Sorry for the mistake.... Actually My code is not working and I mention that in the comment section but no one response yet...that's why ask the same question again.

Comment: @freedomn-m....I understand. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you use change event then it can be solved easily.

```
$('#delivery_charge').on('change',function() {
            var total_amount = parseFloat($('.total_amount').val());
            var delivery_charge = parseFloat($(this).val());
            var grand_total_amount = parseFloat(total_amount + delivery_charge).toFixed(2);
            $('.total_amount').val(grand_total_amount);
});
```

Comment: This still has OPs original problem - put in multiple values and you cumulative results.